# How do I get this array to output the average, sum, and product?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm working through a fundamentals course on JavaScript. I was given this assignment on arrays:

"Using a loop, have the user enter a set of integers using prompt(). Add each entry to an array called myIntegers. Once the user is done entering integers have them enter ‘xxx.’

When the user has completed their data entry, provide the sum, average and product (result of multiplication) of the integers"

Here's the code I have so far (not including the standard HTML div and script which is on another page):

```
let myIntegers = [];
let input = "";
let average = "";
let sum = "";
let product = "";

while(input !="xxx"){
    input = prompt("Add numbers, end using xxx.");
    if(input!="xxx"){
      myIntegers.push(input);  
    } 
}
    console.log(myIntegers);

for(let x = 0; x < myIntegers.length; x++){
    average = average + myIntegers[x]
}
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
    average / myIntegers.length;

for(let y=0; y < myIntegers.length; y++){
    sum = sum + myIntegers[y];
}
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
    sum;

for(let z=0; z < myIntegers.length; z++){
    product = product + myIntegers[z];
}
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
    product * myIntegers;
```

This code presents "NaN" but the array in the console looks good. I've tried turning the prompt into numbers and I've changed up the order of the elements a dozen times. This code makes logical sense to me (except for the product, I'm not the best at math) but just doesn't output what I want.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text submitted by the user in the prompt is returned as a string or null. So, to perform any athematic operations on it, we need to parse it into the integer or float data type first.
Also, take care while initialization the variables, as if we define them with "", then the var will act as string type, and the + operation act as concatenation instead of addition.
Ex.[Example of var intialized as "" act as string type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnXiZ.png)

You can use the following possible code snippet to perform the same required task.

```js
let myIntegers = [];
let input = 0;
let average = 0;
let sum = 0;
let product = 1;

while (input != "xxx") {
    input = prompt("Add numbers, end using xxx.");
    if (input != "xxx") {
        myIntegers.push(input);
    }
}
console.log(myIntegers);

for (let y = 0; y < myIntegers.length; y++) {
    sum = sum + parseFloat(myIntegers[y]);
    product = product * parseFloat(myIntegers[y]);
}

console.log(sum, product, sum/myIntegers.length);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'sum = '+ sum + ' product = '+ product + ' average = ' + (sum/myIntegers.length);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myIntegers = [], input = "", sum = 0, product = 1;

while(input !="xxx"){
    input = prompt("Add numbers, end using xxx.");
    if(input!="xxx"){
      myIntegers.push(input);  
    } 
}
    console.log(myIntegers);

for(let x = 0; x < myIntegers.length; x++){
    sum = sum + (parseFloat(myIntegers[x]) || 0);
     product = product * (parseFloat(myIntegers[x]) || 1);
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `sum = ${sum}, product = ${product}, avg = ${sum/myIntegers.length}`
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myIntegers = [];
let input = '';
let average = 0;
let sum = 0;
let product = 1;

while(input !="xxx"){
    input = prompt("Add numbers, end using xxx.");
    if(input!="xxx"){
      myIntegers.push(Number(input));  
    } 
}
console.log(myIntegers);

for(let x = 0; x < myIntegers.length; x++){
    average += myIntegers[x];
}
console.log(average / myIntegers.length);

for(let y=0; y < myIntegers.length; y++){
    sum += myIntegers[y];
}
console.log(sum);

for(let z=0; z < myIntegers.length; z++){
    product *= myIntegers[z];
}
console.log(product);
```

I've tried to leave the code as closer to one that you wrote as possible. I've just modified the DOM methods adding the `console.log()` and modified the arithmetic operators with the assignment operators.

That said, I think I found 2 main problems:

1. The `prompt()` method returns a `string` so, if you don't convert that `string` to a `number`, every successive arithmetic operation done with the `for` loops will be executed with the strings (that's why I used the `Number()` method inside the `if` statement block). And there are problems when you execute arithmetic operations with the strings (the `+` operator it is used to concatenate strings and if you try to use it in a context like `1 + '1'` you will end with possible unexpected results like `'11'` and not `2` because it will convert the previous or following operand in a string, if there is any string around in the expression (e.g. `1 + 1 + '1'` is `'21'` and `'2' + 1 + 1` is `'211'`). Any other operation will work as expected (e.g. `'3' * 2` will be `6` and not `'32'`). More info here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp ).
2. The second problem, correlated with the first one, it is about your `average`, `sum` and `product` variable initialisation. They are initialised with an empty string and every operation performed on an empty string (be it, well, a `string`!) will follow the rules stated at point 1.

Have a good day!